# The Sum of large Integers using Arrays

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that sums up the total of two large numbers. I used two arrays for the numbers to sum up and the third array to store the result of the summation, But I am getting the wrong output, would you check?

Here is my method:

```
public static int [] sumBigInt(int [] A, int [] B, int n) 
    {
        int sumPerCol = 0;
        int carriedValue = 0;           
        int[] totalArray = new int[A.length + 1];           
        for(int i = A.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            sumPerCol = A[i] + B[i] + carriedValue;             

            if( i == 0)
                totalArray[i] = carriedValue;

            else if(sumPerCol >= 10)
            {   
                carriedValue = sumPerCol / 10;
                totalArray[i] = sumPerCol % 10;
            }
            else
            {
                totalArray[i] = sumPerCol;
                carriedValue = 0;
            }
        }// end of for-Loop         
        return totalArray;      
    }
```

**** In main, I am not getting the correct output:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println(TwoTo_n(8));

        int[] arrayA = {6,9,4,6,9,1,8,9,3,5,6};
        int[] arrayB = {5,9,6,4,3,1,6,7,6,9,5};

        int[] arrayTest = new int[arrayA.length + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayTest.length; i++)
            arrayTest[i] = sumBigInt(arrayA, arrayB, 14)[i];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayTest.length; i++)
            System.out.print(arrayTest[i] + " ");   
    }
```

Here is the output I get :
1 9 1 1 2 3 5 7 0 5 1 0

The output should be:
1 2 9 1 1 2 3 5 7 0 5 1 => now the digit in position 1 disappears :(

There is ONE digit missing; that digit should be added at position zero in my final array, but its not showing up.

Thank you

Comment: What is the 3rd parameter that you are passing?

Comment: Your for loop will cause your function to get once for each position in the array rather than once in total, which is much slower (although you most likely won't notice the difference for such small arrays). You can get rid of the loop and just directly assign the output to `arrayTest`, either in the initialization or separately, e.g. `int[] arrayTest = sumBigInt(arrayA, arrayB, 14)`.

Comment: I added another if-statement when (i == 0) but still not getting the corret output:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. In order to fix it, think what happens to `carriedValue` after you finish the loop:

- When the loop ends, and `carriedValue` is zero, your program returns the correct value
- When the loop ends, and `carriedValue` is one, the most significant digit of the result gets dropped.

All you need to do to fix this is to "shift" digit positions in your `totalArray` by one, and assign `carriedValue` to the top digit after the end of the loop:

```
for(int i = A.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    sumPerCol = A[i] + B[i] + carriedValue;             
    if(sumPerCol >= 10) { 
        carriedValue = sumPerCol / 10;
        totalArray[i+1] = sumPerCol % 10;
    } else {
        totalArray[i+1] = sumPerCol;
        carriedValue = 0;
    }
}// end of for-Loop 
totalArray[0] = carriedValue;
```

Note the use of `totalArray[i+1]` in place of `totalArray[i]`. This is because your method automatically extends the number of significant digits by one. You could change this behavior by re-allocating the array and copying data into it only when `carriedValue` is non-zero.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/0Q9eSY)

Comment: @Mike Please see a demo, it returns the correct result.